# Angular controller can't detect Braintree payment nonce dynamically inputed field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, braintree

Braintree's customer creation SDK system generates a nonce input field in the form as soon as you hit submit.

```
<input name="payment_method_nonce" type="hidden" value="nonce-here">
```

However, with Angular's ng-model input identification system I can't detect the dynamically generated input in my controller. I'm executing a function in my controller as soon as the form is submitted.

```
<form id="checkout" id="checkout" ng-submit="processForm(formData)">
```

As you can see, there's no way to collect the value of the nonce and submit it to a brain tree API command such as creating a new user's payment method.

From the controller the data would be submitted to the braintree api command below using $http.

```
gateway.customer.create({
creditCard: {
token: "creditCard123",
},
paymentMethodNonce: "nonce-from-the-client"
}, function (err, result) {
});
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I just jerry-rig a solution using pure node even though this application is in Angular/express? Or should I use jquery/angular to implant a ng-model in the said input field?

Answer (score 6):

I work at Braintree on the SDK team.

You can use a callback to listen for the nonce instead of having it automatically written to the DOM.

```
braintree.setup('CLIENT_TOKEN', 'dropin', {
    container: 'container',
    paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
      // Do something with the nonce here
    }
});
```

This will also prevent the form from being automatically submitted on your behalf. You can read some further documentation [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/sdk/client/drop-in). If you continue to encounter issues, feel free to reach out to support@getbraintree.com.

Comment: Hello there, Does this work for Credit card tokenization as well? or is it just for the Drop in UI?
I feel (like it is my case) most developers will need to use their own custom built UI.

Comment: Just a note, according to the Braintree JS SDK v2 docs, "The option ```paymentMethodNonceReceived``` has been deprecated in favor of ```onPaymentMethodReceived.```". Update callback looks like ```onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj){ ... }```.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by experimenting with putting the Braintree setup code in the angular controller and writing the post url call in node. I wanted to use Angular for as much as possible but writing the urls in Angular .Config routes didn't seem to be possible. Both answers I received helped me get it working. Thank you both.

In controller

```
$scope.$watch('cToken', function (newVal, oldVal) { //Watch for client token to be loaded then place in braintree.setup api call.
    if (!newVal) return;
    if (newVal){
      console.log('set braintree');
      braintree.setup($scope.cToken, 'custom', {
      id: "checkout",
      paymentMethodNonceReceived: function (event, nonce) {
              // Do something with the nonce here
              event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

In node.js app.js

```
app.post('/api/generateNonce', routes.generateNonce);
exports.generateNonce = function(req, res){
var nonce = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
console.log('nonce '+nonce);

gateway.customer.create({
  id: 'clientId2222',
  paymentMethodNonce: nonce
}, function (err, result) {
  var result = JSON.stringify(result);
  console.log('result '+ result);
  console.log(result.success);
  console.log(result.message);
  // e.g f28wm
});

res.send(nonce);
}
```

And front end.

```
<form  name="creatClientForm" class="css-form" id="checkout" action="/api/generateNonce" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input data-braintree-name="number" value="4111111111111111">
      <input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" value="10/20">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submitform">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @kdetella said, using `paymentMethodNonceReceived` should allow you to intercept the nonce instead of picking it up from the DOM.

If it would make things easier, you can use [braintree-angular](https://github.com/jeffcarp/braintree-angular) for a slightly neater integration with Angular. Here's [an example](https://github.com/jeffcarp/braintree-angular/blob/master/examples/dropin/nonce-received.html) of using `paymentMethodNonceReceived`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Yes I've looked at braintree-angular. I'm using custom form fields instead of dropin but I don't think that should matter. The problem is that event.preventDefault(); doesn't seem to work on  angular ng-model form, nor does paymentMethodNonceReceived truely disable to form if I'm using angular ng-model. ng-submit="processForm(formData)" executes the processForm() function upon hitting submit no matter what.